# Angular Strap Datepicker: Inconsistent timestamps returned, UTC +0 vs UTC +12 hours

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, timestamp, angular-strap

**Situation:**

- We are using Angular-Strap's [datepicker](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers) and want to return UTC timestamps to the server.
- When selecting a date (no time selection) we found out that some computers return a timestamp with a time of 0:00, and some with a time of 12:00.
- This was browser independent, but differed between computers.

**Problem:**

- Some computers return 0:00, some 12:00.

**What I tried:**

- While debugging I found out that the problem arose at line 379 of [angular-strap/dist/modules/datepicker.js#L379](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/dist/modules/datepicker.js#L379), the controller.$dateValue returns 'Sat Mar 28 1987 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)' instead of 'Sat Mar 28 1987 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)', the value that is returned by other computers.

**Question:**

- How to return a 0:00 time in all situations?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a same kind of problem. What I did is wrote a directive to convert the date utc Date. check the code sample. This solve my problem.

```
(function (angular) {
angular.module('myApp').directive('datePicker', ['$parse', 'dateFilter', function           ($parse, dateFilter) {
    var inputDateFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy';

    var utcDateGeneretor = function (dateString) {
        if ('undefined' === typeof dateString || '' === dateString) {
            return null;
        }

        var parts = dateString.split('/');
        if (3 !== parts.length) {
            return null;
        }
        var year = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
        var month = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
        var day = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        if (year.toString().length < 4) {
            return null;
        }

        if (month < 0 || year < 0 || day < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        //Javascript month is zero based. thats why always reduce 1 form selected month.
        return new Date(Date.UTC(year, (month - 1), day));
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

            var mindatecalvalue = parseInt(attrs["mindatecalvalue"], 10);
            var maxdatecalvalue = parseInt(attrs["maxdatecalvalue"], 10);
            var twoDigitCutoffSpecified = attrs["twoDigitCutoff"];
            var twoDigitYear1900cutoff = -1;  //If a 2-digityear is less than this number it is treated as being 2000+, otherwise 1900+.
            if (twoDigitCutoffSpecified) {
                twoDigitYear1900cutoff = parseInt(attrs["twoDigitCutoff"], 10);
                if (isNaN(twoDigitYear1900cutoff)) {
                    twoDigitYear1900cutoff = -1;
                } else if (twoDigitYear1900cutoff <= 0) {
                    twoDigitYear1900cutoff += (new Date().getFullYear() - 2000); //A negative number is interpreted as a number of years before the current year.
                }
            }

            var updateModel = function (dateText) {

                var canonicalisedDateText = ensureFullYear(dateText, twoDigitYear1900cutoff);

                // call $apply to bring stuff to angular model
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrls.$setViewValue(canonicalisedDateText);
                });
                ctrls.$render();
            };

            var ensureFullYear = function (dateText, twoDigitYear1900cutoff) {
                var findYearRegex = /(.+[^0-9])([0-9]+)\s*$/;
                var dateParts = findYearRegex.exec(dateText);
                if ((!dateParts) || (dateParts.length != 3)) {
                    return dateText; //can't find a year in this date.
                }
                var originalYearAsStr = dateParts[2];
                if (originalYearAsStr.length > 2) {
                    return dateText; //Not a 2-digit year.
                }
                var originalYear = parseInt(originalYearAsStr, 10);
                var fullYear = 0;
                if (originalYear <= twoDigitYear1900cutoff) {
                    fullYear = 2000 + originalYear;
                } else {
                    fullYear = 1900 + originalYear;
                }
                var restOfDate = dateParts[1];
                return restOfDate + fullYear;
            }


            ctrls.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                return dateFilter(modelValue, inputDateFormat);
            });

            ctrls.$parsers.push(function (dateString) {
                return utcDateGeneretor(dateString);
            });
        }
    };
}]);

})(angular);
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had faced similar problem regarding date-only selection... I solved it using ng-model's $parsers.

```
    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (datepickerValue) {
        return moment(datepickerValue).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    });
```

I am using moment.js for date handling. but above solution can work even without moment.js, 
like below. (note : i havent tested below code, so you might need to tweak it a little bit)

```
    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (datepickerValue) {
        //return new Date(datepickerValue).toISOString().substring(0,10);
        return new Date(datepickerValue).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    });
```

above will give you date without timestamp. But if your requirement says that you always need 0:00 at the end, that can also be achieved very easily...

```
    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (datepickerValue) {
        return moment(datepickerValue).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + " 0:00";
    });
```

the complete directive code which i used for this is:

```
shared.directive("dateToIso", function () {

    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (datepickerValue) {
            return moment(datepickerValue).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
```

I have defined it as an attribute, so that you can use it with other directives you have. you can use it like below...

```
          <input type="text" ng-model="myDate" name="date" bs-datepicker date-to-iso>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of fixing the bug in your local copy of AngularStrap you can create a directive to wrap the DatePicker directive.  I grabbed the plunker from angular-strap and wrote a decorator directive to always return 0:00 time for all situations.  This is nice because you can write all the custom logic you need inside a directive.  Notice - this directive creates a watch on the model and then performs any modifications needed post update and returns it to your app's controller via callback.  Note: I also switched to moment.js for ease of use.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgPbhI3U5ykhtF2r6MGx?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<date-wrapper></date-wrapper>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('dateWrapper', function($compile) {
  return {
      restrict:'AE',
      link:function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

          var html = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" ng-model="selectedDate" bs-datepicker>';

          var e = $compile(html)(scope);
          element.replaceWith(e);

          scope.$watch('selectedDate', function(date) {        
              var updatedDate = moment.utc(date).hour(0).minute(0).second(0).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z");

              scope.dateChanged(updatedDate);
          });
      }
  }
});
```

Apps controller example:

```
// call back for updated date
$scope.dateChanged = function(date) {
    $scope.selectedZeroHourUtcDate = date;
};
```